# FQL Reference for Querytext Qualifiers Such As Filename

Tags: search, fast-search, search-api

Is there an MSDN / TechNet or other reference for FQL (FAST Query Language) that shows the querytext qualifiers such as filename? For any SharePoint version (2010/2013/2016).

For example, this query works:
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='filename:christmas.docx'

and returns documents with that file name (or fragment, I haven't tested that).

I can't find any mention of the "filename" qualifier in the official FQL references such as [FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff394606.aspx), or the various blogs and articles that I reviewed, except a few Stack questions.

Comment: have you tried this tool http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/?

Comment: Yes, I don't see anywhere that it handles querytext qualifiers. Please point that out if it does.

Comment: These are just Queryable Managed Properties and KQL (Keyword Query Language).

Answer (score 1):

Filter out all The queryable managed Properties from this list and you have all the default ones: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx

Then there are all the autogenerated ones, which you can get my listing all queryable properties in you environment, UI or PowerShell.